# Are minus-primorial-primes rarer than plus-primorial primes?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

Here

https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=PrimorialPrime

it can be seen that the largest known primorial prime of the form $p\#-1$ is far
smaller than the largest known primorial prime of the form $p\#+1$. I do not see
a reason why a plus-primorial number has a bigger probability to be prime.

> Is this result pure chance, or is there a mathematical reason ?

Comment: There is no such discrepance for the factorial primes : http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/FactorialPrime.html

Comment: I don't immediately see any reason that it's due to anything but chance.

Comment: Does the question really make sense ? Your link doesn't suggest the $\pm $ primorial primes are not equidistributed